# Understanding a proof involving the exponential function

Tags: real-analysis, derivatives, proof-explanation, exponential-function

In an exercise sheet from my real analysis lectures, there is a question I have been stuck on for some time. I will attach the solution from the notes in the hope that someone can 'fill in the gaps' and help me understand.

Question: Suppose that $f(x)$ satisfies $f(x+y) = f(x)f(y)$, prove that if $f$ is differentiable then either $f(x)=0$ or $f(x)=e^{ax}$.

I have attached the proof in picture form so that you can see the spots I'm getting confused at:
[image]

For clarity, I do not understand how the derivative in the first part has been calculated and what might make you try to calculate the $y$ derivative at $y=0$. Also why do we have an $a$ in $e^{ax}$?

Comment: What exactly are you confused about?

Comment: Excuse me, I have attatched an edit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason you take the derivative with respect to $y$ and evaluate it at $y=0$ is to obtain an ODE for $f$.

This derivative is calculated in two ways. The first is taking the derivative of $f(x+y)$ with respect to $y$ (i.e. $f^\prime (x+y)$) and evaluating it at $y=0$. which gives $f^\prime (x)$. The second way it's computed is by taking the derivative with respect to $y$ of $f(x)f(y)$ and evaluating it at zero, which gives $f(x) f^\prime (0)$.

You now have a differential equation of the form $\frac{dy}{dx} =\alpha y$ whose solution is of the form $Ce^{\alpha x}$. In your case, $\alpha = f^\prime(0)$, which gives your desired solution.